# Visual Studio Expand/Collapse Button Missing In Aspx File

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

As you can see on the image below my aspx files does not have collapse/expand buttons ("-" and "+") How can I enable them again? thanks in advance. Running VS2010.

[image: No Collapse]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a bunch of information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td6a5x4s(v=vs.80).aspx).

Note the section on the Outlining submenu in the Edit menu.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I selected "Start Automatic Outlining" and then it worked like a charm :)

Comment: But, it goes away when I restart visual studio. Also, its a page by page setting to be done.

Comment: You can define it for the environment as well not only for the page: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> (C#) -> Advanced -> Enter outlining mode when files open

Comment: Mine disappeared all of a sudden, just wanted them back, went to edit/outlining/start automatic outlining

Comment: Great automatic outlining that needs to be started manually :(  that sorted it for me

Comment: There is no actual help here. Link is not an answer, especially since this link has expired documentation:  Visual Studio 2005 Retired documentation

Comment: @Enkode: The answer was posted to a question from 2011. Were you expecting the information to be up to date for 2021? How does that make any sense? Obviously, many people found it helpful.

Comment: @JonathanWood, I don't expect it to be up to date, it most likely helped people because the link showed a solution. But it is not answer, just a link according to StackOverflow is not really an answer. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info

Answer (score 51):

Follow this menu command:

**Edit > Outlining > Start Automatic Outlining**

Comment: I did this with the Quick launch in visual studio2012 and got an alert that the command was not available at the moment. But it did work. I have the fold option back on the left side. The alertwindow was a bug I think.

Comment: Thanks for the not "Just follow the *maybe* broken link and I won't tell you about the solution here" answer.

Comment: Agreed with Beytan, straight forward answer

Answer (score 15):

[image]

For those who want to get in first view and do not want to visit above link.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

(to save document)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

(to reformat document)

Answer (score 0):

Re-enabling outlining isn't working to resolve my issue.  The (-/+) is only missing from spanning comments (/*...*/).  Yet my Hide/Show Comments add-on is still recognizing the comments when I hide all with that.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the file from the project and include again. This will make the expand/collapse buttons show up immediately.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).